# Null pointer Exception in currency converter android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am building currency converter for android and am getting null pointer exception in this code.I am converting all the values as the number is entered in the edit text,All the values in the text views are changed.Please help !!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText currency;
String value;
float us,pk,om,ks,e;
TextView usa,pak,uk,oman,ksa,eu;
float val;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        value=currency.getText().toString();
        usa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        pak=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        uk=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        oman=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        ksa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        eu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        currency=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        currency.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

                value=currency.getText().toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                   val = Float.parseFloat(value);
                   us=val*3.67f;
                   usa.setText(Float.toString(us));
                   pk=val=26.95f*val;
                   pak.setText(Float.toString(pk));
                   om=val*0.10f;
                   oman.setText(Float.toString(om));

                   ks=val*1.02f;
                   ksa.setText(Float.toString(ks));

                   e=val*0.20f;

                   eu.setText(Float.toString(e));
                }


            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                        val = 0.0f; 
                        usa.setText("0");
                        pak.setText("0");
                        uk.setText("0");
                        oman.setText("0");
                        ksa.setText("0");
                        eu.setText("0");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Float.toString(val), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    //us=val*3.67;
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int aft

er) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
            });




        //val=Double.parseDouble(value);
    //  us=val*3.67;
    //  usa.setText(String.valueOf(us));
    }
```

Trace:

```
    08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{omnia.android.nfc/omnia.android.nfc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 17:35:03.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2944):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
```

Comment: Please add the full stactrace and mark the line, where the exception occured.

Comment: You are using currency object without initializing it. Please refer bbZ answer

Comment: @Talib there must be more, somethig theat point to the NullPointerException.

Comment: @Talib look to the answer of bbz you try to get the currency value, before you get the curreny field.

Comment: @Talib are you still getting NullPointerException after changing your code like I pointed out in my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...

currency=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

value=currency.getText().toString();
usa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
pak=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
uk=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
oman=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
ksa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
eu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);

...
```

Move the currency here.

You are trying to get currency data without initiating it.